# How to add NHunspell dictionary in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nhunspell

I'm new to VS and trying to use NHunSpell in my project.  After the usual effort, I think I'm on the right track and one last problem remains: how to add the `.dic` and `.aff` files and have them present in my project.

I've installed NHunSpell via NuGet so it's included in the project when I commit.

So far, I have tried:

- Putting the files in the all of the `.dll` directories
- Adding them as a resource in the project properties
- Embedding them in the project as an "embedded resource" with "copy always"
- Embedding them in the project as an "resource" with "copy always"

The problem is that the Hunspell constructor expects two string arguments pointing to the files, like so:

```
 Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_us.dic");
```

...so even when I am successful at adding them as a resource, they are a) byte arrays and b) not included when I build the project.  I have built the project successfully with absolute paths to the local machine, but this obviously isn't optimal.

So, how can I add these paths to the build (and subsequent commit so future pull-ers can use them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah-ha - after way too long, looks like the solution is `Server.MapPath`:

```
Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell(
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Assets/dictionaries/en_us.aff"),
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Assets/dictionaries/en_us.dic")
);
```

To test where the base path is, you can use:

```
string s = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```